# Can't read properly a json file

Tags: javascript, angular8

I'm new here, and I did not find any answer to my question, or may-be I did not look up in the right way. I started my intership yesterday, and this is my first time using Angular. For now, I am working on reading a json file and getting some informations, however I tested with a syntax and it worked, but the file sent by the server is a bit different. I've been testing with this json file (not the one from the company)

```
[
    {"name": "Justine", "age": 25, "sexe": "femme"},
    {"name": "Alex", "age": 23, "sexe": "homme"}
]
```

But if I turn [ into {, it does not work anymore

```
{
    {"name": "Justine", "age": 25, "sexe": "femme"},
    {"name": "Alex", "age": 23, "sexe": "homme"}
}
```

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : This is the code of the component

```
import { InformationsService } from '../informations.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  template: `<h2> Liste </h2>
    <ul *ngFor="let f of info"> 
      <li>{{f.name}} <br></li>
    </ul>`,
  styles: []
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  public info = [];

  constructor(private _info : InformationsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._info.getInfo().subscribe(data => (this.info = data));
  }

}
```

The code of the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Info } from './informations';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InformationsService {

  private _url: string = "/assets/data/file.json";
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  getInfo(): Observable<Info[]>{
    return this.http.get<Info[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

I forgot to say that my file is from an API and there is no [, only {

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet?

Comment: [ ] is the syntax for lists. What's the issue with it?

Comment: Why should it work? An object needs keys. https://www.json.org/

Comment: First you need to know that you cannot simply change they syntax of the JSON. **[]** defines an object while **{}** defines an array with _key_/_value_ pairs.

Comment: don't turn the '[' into '{'. Why would you want to do that ? The first json is good.

Answer (score 0):

You need put your data inside a root property of your json

```
{
   "root": [
        {"name": "Justine", "age": 25, "sexe": "femme"},
        {"name": "Alex", "age": 23, "sexe": "homme"}
       ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my issue to be more specific.
I think the way I did first does not work with a JSON:API. But I don't really know what I have to change though